# Calculate ranks for each group

Tags: r, plyr, ranking

I have a `df` with types and values. I want to rank them in order of `x` within `type` and give a count of how many other rows row `n` has  higher value of `x` than (column `pos`).

e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),x=c(1,77,1,34,1,8))
# for type a row 3 has a higher x than row 1 and 2 so has a pos value of 2
```

I can do this with:

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(type = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),x=c(1,77,1,34,1,8))
df <- ddply(df,.(type), function(x) x[with(x, order(x)) ,])
df <- ddply(df,.(type), transform, pos = (seq_along(x)-1) )

     type  x pos
1    a  1   0
2    a  1   1
3    a 77   2
4    b  1   0
5    b  8   1
6    b 34   2
```

But this approach does not take into account ties between type `a` row 1 and 2. Whats the easiest way to get the output where ties have the same value e.g.

```
     type  x pos
 1    a  1   0
 2    a  1   0
 3    a 77   2
 4    b  1   0
 5    b  8   1
 6    b 34   2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ddply(df,.(type), transform, pos = rank(x,ties.method ="min")-1)

  type  x pos
1    a  1   0
2    a 77   2
3    a  1   0
4    b 34   2
5    b  1   0
6    b  8   1
```

Comment: just read `min` it makes the ties have the minimum value in the seqeunce they are found in the vector. otherwise my ties would both have a value of 1

Comment: Or, sticking with base R, but with an otherwise identical approach, `within(df, {pos <- ave(x, type, FUN=function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "min")-1)})`, and with "data.table" (assuming the `data.table` is named "DT"), `DT[, list(x, pos = rank(x, ties.method="min")-1), by = "type"]`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto `DT[,pos:=rank(x,ties.method ="min")-1, by = type]`

Comment: Yes indeed. Assignment by reference slipped my mind there. I'll chalk it up to it being late night in India.